# How to read JSON with unknown key in ReasonML?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript, bs-json

I am writing a simple application that display dog images from [Dog API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/). I used bs-json to make it a record and use it later. The list of breeds can be obtained by the API. The response looks like this.

```json
{
 "message": {
  "breed": ["array of sub-breeds"],
  "breed without subbreed": [],
  ...
  },
"status": "success"
}
```

So the key is not known at the compile time. If I add it one by one, it would be some kind of hardcode. I only want breeds not sub-breeds. If possible, I would like an array of them.

```
[| "chihuahua", "golden retreiver", ... |] // Something like this so I can make a select input
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just decode into a `Js.Dict.t` and then take its keys.

Something like:

```ml
let decodeBreeds: Js.Json.t => array(string) =
  Json.Decode.(dict(id) |> map(Js.Dict.keys))
```

Comment: I used on the object and get [| "message", "status", "code"|].

Comment: This is just to decode the breeds object. You can use `field("message", decodeBreeds)` on the outer object if you just want the breeds from it.